# Why TBATS model giving poor result?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, tbats

I have time series data of number of units ordered from a manufacturing plant and number of units delivered. The are multiple different plant sites for which I need to build forecasting models. I started with one plant and used ARIMA models with seasonality and differencing of order 1 to induce stationarity. The model performance was decent but not very good. Here is the R code

```
model = auto.arima(log(train),d=1, seasonal = T)

f = forecast(model, 10)
p = exp(f$mean) 
mape(test,p)*100
```

At this stage I had monthly data and number of data points was only 31 for each plant. Due to fewer data points I could not try other approaches. To improve the model I collected weekly data and tried other approaches. Since I had weekly data, I thought of modelling complex seasonal patterns using TBATS. Here is the R code

```
y <- msts(train_a, seasonal.periods=12)
fit <- tbats(y) 
fc <- forecast(fit,h=5001)
```

To my surprise, I got insanely high MAPE using this method, which made me feel I am doing something wrong. I went back to try ARIMA again on weekly data. However, I noticed that if I used `log(train_a)` to train the model I get the error which says "No suitable ARIMA model found". And if I use `train_a` to train the model I get almost the same high MAPE I got with TBATS.

1. I am not sure why using weekly data (around 2500 data points) is giving very high error but using monthly data points (only 31 data points) was giving decent result (although not very good). What am I doing wrong here ?
2. Given the result with TBATS was very poor, how can I check if TBATS is the appropriate model to use?
3. When should I consider going for additive time series models such as those of `prophet` library?
4. What could be some of the ways I can look at to improve the prediction accuracy?

Comment: Analyzing weekly data in general is not a good idea while daily data and monthly data can have useful patterns. This is due in part to the 53 week issue and that activity for the j th week of a year is not necessarily reproduced every year whereas daily data usually has strong patterns and monthly series similarly ... NOT SO weekly !. Additionally holiday effects and long weekend effects often create issues .

Comment: @IrishStat Thanks for your comment. I tried with monthly data initially but the model performance was not good, which could likely be due to fewer number of data points. It's not possible for me to get daily data as the company I work with collects weekly data only. Could your suggest ways on how to go about improving it ?

Comment: It is often possible to incorporate weekly dummies and/or level shifts while also treating arima structure. Why don't you post one of your weekly data sets and I will try and help further.

Comment: you have 33 values .. are these monthly sums or are they weekly sums . you said you had 31 monthly values ?

Comment: My bad, I accidentally posted the monthly data. Let me just get the weekly data and I will post it then.

Comment: Here is 47 week data for one plant: 
600188,
1474332,
1764480,
4501748,
638978,
1410116,
2359624,
3577692,
1540400,
2096944,
1729844,
2046916,
4479828,
1378832,
1360384,
1562646,
3546402,
1003902,
1273794,
1646558,
3490476,
1041898,
1509698,
1762512,
2085656,
3733219,
1314034,
1472608,
1782192,
2350811,
1367302,
1501768,
1396170,
3285756,
1073122,
1433666,
1916046,
1913576,
2967130,
1083428,
1791398,
1774624,
2727810,
894408,
1680798,
1693518,
2303190

Comment: with 47 weeks one can't get any seasonal structure ...can u provide more

Answer (score 2):

**1. I am not sure why using weekly data (around 2500 data points) is giving very high error but using monthly data points (only 31 data points) was giving decent result (although not very good). What am I doing wrong here ?**

@IrishStat is likely right. The 53rd week issue is rough.

It is usually easier to get clear seasonality with monthly data or daily data. If you want to forecast at the monthly level one option is to take monthly values then divide the monthly forecast into weekly forecasts using proportions from last years data. This is very adhoc, if there is a large trend this method would likely not work.

If possible I prefer to work with daily data and aggregate up. Daily data usually has weekly seasonality and yearly seasonality. You asked about `prophet`. I have seen good results on daily data with `prophet`.

**2. Given the result with TBATS was very poor, how can I check if TBATS is the appropriate model to use?**

In general comparing AIC or having a hold-out test set is the way forecasters determine what to use. I am not sure why TBATs is giving poor results. You can always try using ARIMA with fourier regressors if you want something analogous to TBATS.

**3. When should I consider going for additive time series models such as those of `prophet` library?**

Daily data with multiple seasonalities.

**4. What could be some of the ways I can look at to improve the prediction accuracy?**

1. *Always use a benchmark!*
2. Combine forecasts from multiple methods

If I assume that your data has seasonality of 4, thinking that week 1 of month 12 is like week 1 of month 11, then these are the results I get.

tbats

```
                  ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
Training set 303940.9 992404.8 660849.8 -3.715019 33.47303 1.0359822 -0.2295624        NA
Test set     127521.3 663545.9 491123.4 -8.246457 32.40637 0.7699103 -0.4565056 0.2511831
```

arima

```
                    ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
Training set  176783.7 914286.5 557117.1 -0.8916543 24.60861 0.8733655 -0.1641036        NA
Test set     -169576.8 395043.5 304737.5 -8.7959001 16.77696 0.4777222  0.1541620 0.1634051
```

arima with fourier

```
                     ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE     MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
Training set  -26492.66 854052.9 684739.0 -17.12327 38.64117 1.073432  0.1110644        NA
Test set     -290873.37 735399.4 642696.9 -36.66567 49.56333 1.007525 -0.3913094 0.6469734
```

seasonal naive

```
                     ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE     MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
Training set  -19057.05 949002.6 637896.8  -6.941991 28.86181 1.000000 -0.4136366        NA
Test set     -155011.50 167192.4 155011.5 -10.319070 10.31907 0.243004  0.2955041 0.1352975
```

You will see that using seasonal naive on a hold out of 4 weeks with the assumption of seasonality of 4 give the best results on the test set!

## Code

````
library(forecast)
df_weekly <- c(600188, 1474332, 1764480, 4501748, 638978, 1410116, 2359624, 3577692, 1540400, 
               2096944, 1729844, 2046916, 4479828, 1378832, 1360384, 1562646, 3546402, 1003902, 
               1273794, 1646558, 3490476, 1041898, 1509698, 1762512, 2085656, 3733219, 1314034, 
               1472608, 1782192, 2350811, 1367302, 1501768, 1396170, 3285756, 1073122, 1433666, 
               1916046, 1913576, 2967130, 1083428, 1791398, 1774624, 2727810, 894408, 1680798, 
               1693518, 2303190)

ts_weekly <- ts(df_weekly, frequency = 4)

train <- subset(ts_weekly, end=length(ts_weekly)-5)
test <- subset(ts_weekly, start=length(ts_weekly)-4)

benchmark <- snaive(train) %>% forecast(h = 4)
tbats_fit <- tbats(train, seasonal.periods = 52) %>% forecast(h = 4)
arima_fit <- auto.arima(train, lambda = "auto") %>% forecast(h = 4)
# arima with fourier regs
bestfit <- list(aicc=Inf)
for(i in 1:8)
{
  fit <- auto.arima(train, xreg=fourier(train, K=i), seasonal=FALSE)
  if(fit$aicc < bestfit$aicc)
    bestfit <- fit
  else break;
}
arimaf_fit <- forecast(bestfit, xreg=fourier(train, K=1, h=4))

accuracy(tbats_fit, test) 
accuracy(arima_fit, test)
accuracy(arimaf_fit, test)
accuracy(benchmark, test)
```
````

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! Would it be wise to ensemble the best 2 or 3 of these models using simple average so as to reduce variance ?  I averaged the 3 of these and got a MAPE of around 12.6

Comment: Also, when I use the same model as above for data from another plant, I get absurd result - Inf MAPE on train and over 600 on test. Not sure what could be reason. Here is the data - 88000,201600,234925,144600,193800,142800,215280,150080,311160,0,27912,108120,187456,88328,335520,18744,6500,150120,149960,321508,114600,0,372699,0,114100,0,453360,161100,229380,255040,221080,6000,277504,147785,243100,107160

Comment: Yes, the simple average is the way to go. Also, your additional data is not like the previous time series. `ndiffs(new_ts, test = "kpss")` returns 0 and `auto.arima(new_ts)` returns an ARIMA(0,0,0) with a mean of 161218. This means that you would do better to use a random walk forecast or any other method known for forecasting non-seasonal forecasts.

Comment: Noted. Other than random walk forecasts, is there any other model for such data which I can look into ? Random walk forecast using rwf() gives high error.

Comment: Try many methods. Going down the exponential smoothing route may be good, but I will tell you now, you will not get amazing forecasts on that time series. Random walk may be the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I used the 44 values [image] . Visually there appears to be more variability at higher values . This lead the automatic analysis to suggest a log xform using AUTOBOX , a piece of software that I have helped to develop.

Following is the Actual/Fit and Forecast from a useful model in log space (3,0,0)(0,0,0)

The equation is here [image] and here [image]

The model residuals are here [image] with forecasts here [image]

[image]

Since you only have 44 values it is not possible to develop seasonal structure .

As to why TBATS is giving you unacceptable results .. I can not help you . Perhaps it didn't sense the need for a power transform or was thwarted by the anomalies .. I don't know.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I seem to have lost the data set containing more points. I have asked the team for it though. Did you use Autobox for this ? Are there any dependencies which need to be installed to use it ? I tried using it some time back but couldn't, due to some dependency error issue.

Comment: yes I used AUTOBOX  for this . No there are no dependencies that need to be installed. If you have an issue please contact me offline and I will help you .